# How do I align images centrally and responsively in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm really looking for is two different designs to align my images according to. One for tablets (992 px) and up and one for smaller screens.

Ideally I want them to look like this:

This one:
[image: First design]

Should shrink to:
[image: Second design]

That's just an ideal though, really any sort of symmetry would do so long as the red one (it's special) is displayed bottom center.

I'm having big problems getting the images to align in the center using Bootstrap's `col-xx-y` grid formatting. `text-align: center` seems to be the only way to get images to align centrally, which is weird. But it's very fidgety, so if I change anything the design breaks completely.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row centered categories">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
            <h4>Title 1</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
            <h4>Title 2</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
            <h4>Title 3</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
            <h4>Title 4</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
            <h4>Title 5</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
            <h4>Title 6</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
            <h4>Title 7</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
            <h4>Special</h4>

        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
  text-align: center
}

.categories {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}

.icon-cont {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 125px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.icon-cont img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Please see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zmfgcdcf/).

Is this a valid approach to this design? I'm worried I'm doing things totally wrong because it's so fidgety. For example, if I change `col-md-12` to `col-lg-12` it won't center at certain screen sizes (you have to zoom out to see this).

I'm thinking I would have to pair the icons up in smaller `cols` but they just won't work with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each one a column for each device ie

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">
```

etc etc

sorry this is short

here's something to read, when i get a chance i'll create a fiddle :)

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

EDIT:

Hi had a quick whack, this works without any css, just using twitter bootstrap built in columns

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
<div class="row centered categories">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <center>
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
                <h4>Title 1</h4>

        </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <center>
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
                <h4>Title 2</h4>

        </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <center>
            <div class="icon-cont">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
                        <h4>Title 3</h4>

            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <center>
        <div class="icon-cont">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
                <h4>Title 4</h4>

        </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <center>
            <div class="icon-cont">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
                        <h4>Title 5</h4>

            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <center>
            <div class="icon-cont">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
                        <h4>Title 6</h4>

            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <center>
            <div class="icon-cont">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
                        <h4>Title 7</h4>

            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <center>
            <div class="icon-cont">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZF9KgVk.png">
                        <h4>Special</h4>

            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh that's very cool. I can probably tweak this a little to get it looking like my ideal design concept.

Comment: @LyndonJohnson awesome, let me know if you need anymore help. this was as close to your design as i could get; but i didnt know exactly when you wanted it to change

Comment: No I solved it by putting a `max-width` on  `container` so they wouldn't glide too far from each other, then using a `col-sm-offset` on the first icon in each row so I could use smaller `col`s. That got it looking exactly how I wanted it to! Thanks for the initial push in the right direction!